# How can i get couchbase db events for document creation/deletion using spring data couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE, and I use spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase to connect to couchbase database.

What I am looking for is when a document is created/deleted/updated in couchbase bucket to which my spring boot is hooked up, i wanted to get those events. I have looked up the ApplicationListener<CouchbaseMappingEvent<?>>

Here is my CouchbaseListener

```
    @Component
public class CouchbaseEventListener<E> implements ApplicationListener<CouchbaseMappingEvent<?>> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CouchbaseEventListener.class.getName());

    private final Class<?> domainClass;


    private static final String UNKNOWN = "unknown";

    String getKeyValue(CouchbaseDocument doc, String keyName, String def) {
        return doc.containsKey(keyName) ? (String)doc.get(keyName) : def;
    }
    String getKeyValue(CouchbaseDocument doc, String keyName) {
        return getKeyValue(doc, keyName, UNKNOWN);
    }


    public CouchbaseEventListener () {
        Class<?> typeArgument = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), AbstractCouchbaseEventListener.class);
        domainClass = typeArgument == null ? Object.class : typeArgument;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void onApplicationEvent(CouchbaseMappingEvent<?> event) {

        E source = (E) event.getSource();
        // Check for matching domain type and invoke callbacks
        if (source != null && !domainClass.isAssignableFrom(source.getClass())) {
            return;
        }

        if (event instanceof BeforeDeleteEvent) {
            logger.info("================= BeforeDeleteEvent() {}, {}", event.getSource(), event.getDocument());
            onBeforeDelete(event.getSource(), event.getDocument());
            return;
        }
        else if (event instanceof AfterDeleteEvent) {
            onAfterDelete(event.getSource(), event.getDocument());
            return;
        }

        if (event instanceof BeforeConvertEvent) {
            onBeforeConvert(source);
        }
        else if (event instanceof BeforeSaveEvent) {
            logger.info("================= BeforeSaveEvent() {}, {}", event.getSource(), event.getDocument());
            onBeforeSave(source, event.getDocument());
        }
        else if (event instanceof AfterSaveEvent) {
            onAfterSave(source, event.getDocument());
        }
    }


    public void onBeforeConvert(E source) {
      // Something goes here
    }

    public void onBeforeSave(E source, CouchbaseDocument doc) {
    }

    public void onAfterSave(E source, CouchbaseDocument doc) {
        if (doc!=null) {
            String id = (String)doc.getId();
            String wellId = getKeyValue(doc, "wellId", "(null)");
            String data = getFullEventDataString(source, doc, id);
            if (data != null) {
                logger.info("Hello Here := onAfterSave() . {}", data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onAfterDelete(Object source, CouchbaseDocument doc) {
      // something goes here
 
    }

    public void onBeforeDelete(Object source, CouchbaseDocument doc) {
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

   
    }
```

But this does n't work, This class is never getting called, when documents are created/updated/deleted in couchbase. Is there some configurations I have missed.

Comment: You need to send an event from couchbase to your spring app. Use couchbase event service https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/eventing/eventing-examples-rest-via-curl-get.html  Is that you are already doing?

Answer (score 0):

This approach might lead to racing conditions if you have multiple instances of your application running. Ideally, you should use CURL and Eventing:

https://blog.couchbase.com/using-curl-eventing-service-update/

Regarding your question, have you tried to listen to AfterDeleteEvent, AfterSaveEvent, BeforeConvertEvent, BeforeDeleteEvent, BeforeSaveEvent instead?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/mapping/event/CouchbaseMappingEvent.html

If none of this work, I recommend you to open a ticket on https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATACOUCH/issues/ asking for a proper example.